# How to copy IoT Hub stored blobs to an Azure SQL using Data Factory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-iot-hub, azure-blob-storage

We are using the IoT Hub routing feature to store messages into an Azure Blob container. By default it stores the messages in a hierarchical manner - creating a folder structure for year, month, day and so on. Within the folder for each day, it creates multiple block blob binary files. Each file may contain multiple JSON objects, each representing a unique IoT telemetry message.

How can I use Azure Data Factory to copy each of these messages into an Azure SQL database?

[Screenshot from Azure Storage Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/953Xt.png)

[A sample blob file containing multiple messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrhoQ.png)

Comment: what's the file format of the blob, txt, csv or others?

Comment: They seem to be text files, please see the second image.

Comment: The data in these files is  'josn ' format. You want to transfer these files data in the container into Azure SQL database, am I right?

Comment: Correct, I want to get these into an Azure SQL database. While Azure Data Factory tutorials provide examples of how a text/csv file in an Azure blob container can be put into an Azure SQL table, not sure how to handle these files.

Comment: The point is that these files may in different folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams that all the files have the same json schema. Then you could follow my steps.

I created an folder `csv` in my container and have several csv files with json data:
[image]

**Source Dataset:** the data in csv file is json format, so I choose the json format file.

1. choose the container: test
2. import the schema(.json)

[image]

**Source setting:** using wildcard file path to choose all the folder and file in the container.

[image]

**Sink setting:**
[image]

**Mapping:**
[image]

Run the pipeline and check the result in sink table:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked for me wonderfully, thank you for your help!